# How to change the limitation of labels inside of div in wordpress?

Tags: php, wordpress

I tried changing max_input_vars but it didnt worked.I need to know what I need to change to get rid of the limitation or increase it.

Comment: Please share your code which causes this error?.  Running into a hard limit like this is usually indicative of deeper issues.

Comment: It doesn't show any error. I have a plugin, it is called UNI CPO. There you can add suboptions. If I add more than 65 suboptions, and I click save, it tell that he saved but it doesn't show the suboptions. I asked in a community of that plugin because I thinked it was a plugin limitation, but the told me to change max_input_vars. I changed it but it didn't work.

Comment: Ok, seems like an issue with a plugin then (not PHP/Wordpress specifically).  If you paid for it I would suggest reaching out to see if they provide support (you may get a quicker response that way).